# Kubernetes Ingress for 'Job' Kind

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

How do we define a Kubernetes `Ingress` for the backend `kind` Kubernetes `Job`?

Could not find specific reference from the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Job creates Pods as implementation.
An Ingress uses a Service to reach the correct Pods.
In order to make an Ingress for Pods created by a Job make sure that a Service exists with a selector that matches the labels of the Pods created by the Job.
Use that Service in the Ingress as target.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as we did with `Deployment` kind.